# How to get DXGI_ERROR description?

Tags: directx, directx12, error-management

In a D3D12 program, I encounter a DGXI_ERROR (`CreateSharedHandle` return an `int` `<0`), but I could not find a way to translate it into the "error description" or "error name" (or both).

I have a description by Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/dxgi-error

Is there such function out there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (result < 0)
{
    LPWSTR errorText{};
    auto result2 = FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, nullptr, result,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&errorText), 0, nullptr);
    wstringstream o;
    auto justfile = JustFile(file);
    o << caller << "(): " << func << " at " << justfile.c_str() << ":" << line <<
        " [" << GetErrorDescr(result).c_str() << "][" << errorText << "]";
    LogMessage(L"%s\n", o.str().c_str());
    //throw exception();
}
```

and with:

```
inline string GetErrorDescr(int error)
{
    switch (error)
    {
        case DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL:
            return string("DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL: The method call is invalid. For example, a method's parameter may not be a valid pointer.");
        case DXGI_ERROR_WAS_STILL_DRAWING:
            return string("DXGI_ERROR_WAS_STILL_DRAWING: The previous blit operation that is transferring information to or from this surface is incomplete.");
        case E_FAIL:
            return string("E_FAIL: Attempted to create a device with the debug layer enabled and the layer is not installed.");
        case E_INVALIDARG:
            return string("E_INVALIDARG: An invalid parameter was passed to the returning function.");
        case E_OUTOFMEMORY:
            return string("E_OUTOFMEMORY: Direct3D could not allocate sufficient memory to complete the call.");
        case E_NOTIMPL:
            return string("E_NOTIMPL: The method call isn't implemented with the passed parameter combination.");
        case S_FALSE:
            return string("S_FALSE: Alternate success value, indicating a successful but nonstandard completion (the precise meaning depends on context).");
        case S_OK:
            return string("S_OK: No error occurred.");
        default:
            return string("Some other D3D11 error (file not found|too many unique state objects|too many unique view objects).");
    }
}
```

and:

```
inline string JustFile(const char* file)-> string
{
    auto f = string(file);
    replace(f.begin(), f.end(), '\\', '/');
    auto justfile = string(f.substr(f.find_last_of('/') + 1));
    return justfile;
}
```

If more details are required, enable the DGXI debug controller:

```
#if defined(_DEBUG)
    // Enable the debug layer (requires the Graphics Tools "optional feature").
    // NOTE: Enabling the debug layer after device creation will invalidate the active device.
    {
        ComPtr<ID3D12Debug> debugController;
        if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12GetDebugInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&debugController))))
        {
            debugController->EnableDebugLayer();
            dxgiFactoryFlags |= DXGI_CREATE_FACTORY_DEBUG;
        }
    }
#endif
```

More here: https://walbourn.github.io/dxgi-debug-device/